# All the icons disappeared on W10 after a reboot

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

All my icons disappeared suddenly after a reboot.. See screenshot. I tried to reboot but to no avail. W10 up to date.

Any idea on what to do?

Thanks a lot,

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: also tried to repair the icon cache but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: You have to verify that the icons are still in the program itself. If you go with explorer to where they are supposed to be, if you see them there, try recreating the shorcuts and see if that restores it. If not, you may have a harddisk problem.

Comment: Every icon disappeared, including those in my task bar so not sure it's program related. In Windows explorer, even windows folders don't have icons anymore.

Comment: Does [How to Rebuild a Broken Icon Cache in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/) answer your question?

Comment: Taskbar icons are the same as desktop icons. The fact that its also gone in explorer is really helpful. @DavidPostill's link should help you.

Comment: Just tried it and it did not work for me. I verified with the command dir and it did delete the icons but after logging back in, icons were still missing (desktop, explorer, ...).

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_desk/windows-10-desktop-icons-disappeared/d19af09c-0dbd-4399-a866-3805585832db

Comment: Nope, did not help either as my pc is not in tablet mode, I see files, "Show Icon" is selected, Reycle bin is missing as well. Thanks